# automate the boring stuff with python chapter 3 practice project

Tags: python

please help me.

for the practice project in chapter 3 of 'automate the boring stuff with python', I made my own code. but it has errors I could not fix.

```
def collatz(number):

    if number == 1:
        print('the sequence is done')

    elif number % 2 == 0:
        print(number / 2)
        collatz(number / 2)

    else:
        print(number * 3 + 1)
        collatz(number * 3 + 1)

def begin():

    try:
        num = int(input("enter an integer: "))

    except ValueError:
        print("Please enter an integer greater than 1.")
        begin()

    if not num > 1:
        print("Please enter an integer greater than 1.")
        begin()

    collatz(num)

begin()
```

running it makes a loop error. I have tried to fix it but I just got stuck on it.

Comment: can you add the error? I just ran your code and it works fine. Not sure what you are trying to code.

Comment: you've got yourself into a recursion.

Comment: when you run my code, at first, entering an integer greater than 1, does not make an error. but once you enter an 1 or 0 or less than them, and then if you enter a good integer like 10, 17 etc you can see the error.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

you've missed the base condition for your ***recrusive*** program.
 You need to know ***recursion*** in order to understand how your code is behaving and functioning.
for now, the **iterative** version of your ***recursive*** program is:

```
def collatz(number):

    if number == 1:
        print("the sequence is done")

    elif number % 2 == 0:
        print(number / 2)
        collatz(number / 2)

    else:
        print(number * 3 + 1)
        collatz(number * 3 + 1)


def begin():

    while True:
        try:
            num = int(input("enter an integer: "))
            if not num > 1:
                print("Please enter an integer greater than 1.")
                continue
        except ValueError:
            print("Please enter a valid integer greater than 1.")
            continue
        collatz(num)
        break


if __name__ == "__main__":
    begin()
```

Answer (score 0):

```
def collatz(number):
    if number % 2 == 0:
        print(number // 2)
        return number // 2
    elif number % 2 == 1:
        print(3 * number + 1)
        return 3 * number + 1

try:
    user_input = int(input('Enter a number:\n'))
    new_num = collatz(user_input)
    while new_num != 1:
        new_num = collatz(new_num)
except ValueError:
    print('Please enter an integer')
```

It says to print and return, so you don't need to use recursion. Here's how I did the program. I also used a while loop to repeat the process until a certain condition was met (until the value was 1).